# Why is my algorithm timing out?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization

Here's the problem (from Leetcode):

```
Given an unsorted array of integers, find the length of longest increasing subsequence.

Example:

Input: [10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]
Output: 4 
Explanation: The longest increasing subsequence is [2,3,7,101], therefore the length is 4. 
Note:

There may be more than one LIS combination, it is only necessary for you to return the length.
Your algorithm should run in O(n2) complexity.
```

Here's my solution:

```
memo = {} 
def lis_calc(lower_bound, offset):
    if memo.get((lower_bound, offset), None):
        return memo[(lower_bound, offset)]
    if offset >= len(nums):
        return 0
    if nums[offset] > lower_bound:
        res = max(1 + lis_calc(nums[offset], offset + 1), lis_calc(lower_bound, offset + 1))
    else:
        res = lis_calc(lower_bound, offset + 1)

    memo[(lower_bound, offset)] = res 
    return memo[(lower_bound, offset)]
```

In the worst case (list is already sorted ascending order), we'll have NxN unique function calls, (N values for each arg in pair). However, my algorithm is timing out for very large inputs, which suggests that my algorithm does not have a worst case time cost of O(NxN). Am I doing something incorrectly here? Seems like a straightforward implementation of DP + memoization. The test input that it's timing out on is `list(range(1,2501))`

I invoke the function via `lis_calc(float('-inf'), 0)`

Comment: At each step, you’re making two recursive calls, unless you’re below the lower bound. They have different args, so the memo cache won’t help. And each of those two calls makes two calls, and each of those makes two calls, and so on. So, unless you have some proof that this can only go log N steps before reaching the lower bound, instead of N steps, your code is `O(2**N)`, not `O(N**2)`.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it… you're not caching half the calls each time you double the calls, but you should be caching half of `N-1` out of the `N`, so, the time should be `N * (N+1) + 1`, which is quadratic after all. So maybe there's just some minor flaw that could be fixed? To test this, try just adding a count of the number of calls. Is it bounded by `N * (N+1) + 1`—or, to keep it simple, just `2 * N**2`? And count the number of cache hits; is it close to `N**2 / 2`?

Comment: If the answers are yes and yes, then my answer is wrong, but that's fine; I can just delete it. :)

Comment: Note that your code is performing explicit recursion. This is **not** the same as dynamic programming. DP usually uses an array to store the results so that you do not have to recalculate them every time they are needed.

Comment: You should read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips about how to debug your code. You can use these tips to verify if your algorithm is correct, or find where it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm may not be quadratic, but exponential.

Look at this code:

```
if nums[offset] > lower_bound:
    res = max(1 + lis_calc(nums[offset], offset + 1), lis_calc(lower_bound, offset + 1))
```

At each step, in the worst case, you make two calls. And each of those two calls, worst-case, makes two calls. And each of those four call makes two calls, and so on.

Your algorithm could still be polynomial if one of two things were true:

- If at least half of those new calls were memo-cached, or
- If it were guaranteed that a worst case would reduce to the lower-bound case (which becomes linear) in at worst `log N` steps.

But as far as I can tell, neither of those is true. So, worst case, your algorithm takes `O(2**N)` steps. Which is why it's too slow.

---

Or… maybe that's not true, maybe it's just taking quadratic time with an extra constant factor, and 2500 is right near the edge of where they expected your code to work comfortably, and you just didn't quite pass?

Each time you double the calls, you aren't going to cache half of them—but you should be caching half of `N-1` of them. So your total steps should work out to `N * (N+1) + 1` if everything is going right, but if you got it slightly wrong that could be enough to be off by a factor of 4… Although really, I don't think it would be a great test if a constant factor of 4 at even the very largest number they test is enough to make a difference.